# how can I test the namenode memory usage situation?

Tags: linux, hadoop, memory, mapreduce

As the title.

I try to use jmap -heap pid, top, and ps -aux.
However, I find the memory size showed always changed.
It is really weird. Maybe GC happens in a fix period.

But how can I get the real memory usage situation?
I know how to calculate in theory and I also want to use experiments to test the value.

Thanks.
Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Memory utilized by particular process can be found from `/proc` filesystem. /proc//stat file gives process information such as memory/cpu usage, process state, process priority etc. Please refer `man proc` for details.

Virtual Memory used by `namenode` process :

- Find Process pid

`pid=ps aux | grep namenode | awk '{print $2}'`

- Display memory usage

`cat /proc/$pid/stat | awk '{print $23}'`

**Note:** You can not `vi` files from /proc

Comment: Is it OK to use this method to find the memory usage for a Java process?

Comment: I mean I find java process always changes the memory usage in the system. What is the reason?

Comment: Above method can be used to find memory usage for processes and threads also. 
BTW How are you monitoring change in memory usage?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just try the same command in a short interval. I don't know why. Now I want to collect the average memory usage for namenode.